# How to select table rows count in LINQ?

Tags: c#

How to get a table condition rows count number using LINQ,I get a table from database,and i want to know the table which columns **name  ="title"** and **value ="A"** rows number?

Here is my not perfect code:

```
                  var query=(from result1 
                              in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                              where result1.Field<string>("title")=="A"
                              select result1);
```

if this i must foreach the query to get the count!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Count()` on your query to get count

```
var count=(from result1 
      in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
      where result1.Field<string>("title")=="A"
      select result1).Count();
```

Comment: Don't have this function "Count"!System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data,DataRow> don't contain the define of count

Comment: @user3127259 it has: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907979(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

No need to duplicate the same query code with the addition of the .Count() method at the end just to get the count.  walkhard's solution is the best, and identical to the technique I used myself.  Basically, as follows:

```
var query=(from result1 
                              in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                              where result1.Field<string>("title")=="A"
                              select result1);

int iCount = query.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use build-in `Count`:

```
int count = query.Count();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var countOfRows=(from result1 
                          in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          where result1.title=="A"
                          select result1).Count();
```